# Is there a way to highlight closest series in R dygraphs?

Tags: r, dygraphs

I am using dygraphs for R https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/ and I am wondering is there a way to highlight closest series like it is done in original dygraphs? Demo gallery here: http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/highlighted-series

I am really unfamiliar with CSS nor HTML. Thanks for any help and advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to highlight the series below mouse cursor then you can use *dyHighlight* . Check: [official R-dygraph website](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-series-highlighting.html)

It is a little more tricky to emphasize the name of the highlighted series in the legend. You need to edit the *.highlight* class in separate [css file and add it](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-css-styling.html) to your graph with:

```
your_dygraph %>% dyCSS("dygraph.css")
```

Example of *dygraph.css*:

```
.highlight {
  /*border: 2px solid black;*/
  background-color: #B0B0B0; /* grey background*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the accepted answer just did not work for me with my current versions of the packages involved. Here is my preferred method that worked (from [here](https://gist.github.com/timelyportfolio/cf7b94048ffe7b6a0112) or [here](https://rpubs.com/walkerke/wb_tfr_all)):

```
d1$x$css = "
.dygraph-legend > span {display:none;}
.dygraph-legend > span.highlight { display: inline; }
"
d1
```